# Can I add a bookmark to default browser programmatically in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, web, alias, bookmarks

As title mentioned. Can I add a bookmark linking t a specified web URL programmatically to the system's default browser in cocoa application?

Comment: Is the app sandboxed?

Comment: @trojanfoe Maybe not. I am working on OS X application.